# the_field not outputting as HTML

Tags: php, wordpress

I am helping a buddy out and modifying his Wordpress portfolio for him. I don't use `php` very often so this might be something simple.

In a template I am calling the Wordpress `the_field()` method like so:

```
<?php echo the_field('full_text'); ?>
```

This is outputting the content of the `full_text` just fine however the `full_text` does contain an `<a>` tag which is not being generated as a link and is showing up as:

```
 <a href="http://thelink.com">The Link</a>
```

instead of actually generating the link.

What do I need to do to get any HTML contained in the `full_text` field to show up as HTML and not plain text?

**Edit**

In `custom_fields.php` I've found:

```
            array (
            'key' => 'field_4',
            'label' => 'Full Text',
            'name' => 'full_text',
            'type' => 'textarea',
            'order_no' => 2,
            'instructions' => 'Write about this item.',
            'required' => 0,
            'conditional_logic' => 
            array (
                'status' => 0,
                'rules' => 
                array (
                    0 => 
                    array (
                        'field' => 'null',
                        'operator' => '==',
                        'value' => '',
                    ),
                ),
                'allorany' => 'all',
            ),
            'default_value' => '',
            'formatting' => 'br',
        ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to mcrtr I was informed that the template he was using was using [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) digging deeper I found the field `full_text` was of type `textarea` by changing it to [wysiwyg](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/wysiwyg-editor/) it no longer outputted as plain text.

Comment: Note: The WYSIWYG has the option to disable the visual editor. If you want to embed HTML this should be the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're using Advanced Custom Fields. If so, you need to turn off the "filter content" setting to get the link to show up.

Comment: And how do I go about doing that?

Comment: Are you using Advanced Custom fields? the_field() is not a WordPress thing but part of that plugin. You can tell by checking the plugins section to see if ACF is enabled. If so, look for an "Options" or "Custom Fields" item in your admin to customize the ACF fields, which is where the filter content setting is.

Comment: looks like he is using ACF, however I cant find any settings for it. When I click custom fields on the left bar of the admin, it brings me to what seems should be a list of custom fileds, but the list is empty.

Comment: Try doing a <?php var_dump(the_field('full_text')); ?> to see the raw output of what is in there. If it doesn't contain the link, something is filtering it before you see it on the page. Also, in ACF, sometimes the fields are defined in a PHP file, not in the UI, so you may have to look around in the theme files for that, and or click all the tabs in the Custom fields menu to see what else there is. Might be gone now but was in a previous database or something.

Comment: var_dump still contained the <a> tag, Ive found a custom_fields.php file. Ill put it in my orignal post, how do I turn off the filtering with this?

Comment: If it is in the var_dump, you're golden. Try using get_field instead and write it like this: <?php echo get_field('full_text'); ?> or you can assign it to a variable first like this: 
<?php 
$myfield = get_field('full_text'); 
echo $myfield;
?>

Comment: hmm the `get_field` outputted blank and the second option didnt resolve the issue, maybe i was reading the var dump wrong, it outputted all the text and the <a href... then NULL

Comment: When you made the field, did you change the formatting dropdown from `none` to `HTML` in ACF?

Answer (score 2):

When setting up the field, change the formatting option to `HTML` instead of `none` and it'll keep the `<a>` tag around your link.

You don't need to change it to WYSIWYG in order to keep links as links in ACF.

Comment: Good to know. I think he will appreciate the `WYSIWYG` editor though. :)